# Image function in R takes forever to run

Tags: r, matlab

I have a matrix of size 23,000 by 200 that was read in R as a dataframe but it takes a lot longer to process it than in MATLAB.

For example in MATLAB I type `image(X)` and it takes less than a second, while in R takes ~ a minute to produce the image.

If I do `dim(X)`, it's the same story.

Any ideas why R may be handling such small matrix so inefficiently in comparison with MATLAB?

I like R a lot, just wondering about the possible sources of slow down.

Comment: Did you use a matrix? Type is.matrix(data) first.

Comment: Try viewing is as raster with grid.raster

Comment: `dim` taking any measurable time? Are you sure you haven't pushed your machine into swapping?

Answer (score 8):

The following takes approximately one second.

```
n <- 23000
k <- 200
m <- matrix( rnorm(n*k), nc=n, nr=k )

image(m, useRaster=TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 That's nice. I was about to post `grid.raster` solution that took ~2 seconds on my machine.